# Customised focus on IOS camera

Tags: ios, camera

Is it possible to create our own focus on IOS camera for our application, so that it may recognise the object when the iOS camera is over it.
For example I have an rectangular area on a sheet of paper and when I put the camera in front of the paper it highlights the focus on the rectangular region, like the Face Identifier.

So, is this possible. If yes then how?

Comment: Do you mean "iOS"? IOS is the operating system of Cisco's routers. Routers don't usually have a camera.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't focus, it's shape recognition. IIRC only face recognition is built in so you need to do this yourself or use a 3rd party solution. Doing it yourself you probably want to use [open-cv](http://opencv.org), 3rd party would be something like [metaio](http://www.metaio.com).

Comment: If I have to do this myself then what would be the approach, I mean where to start what to include etc..

Comment: That's a very broad question, you need to do some research about shape recognition in images and read about open-cv (or use metaio, or similar, and be done in 10 minutes and some cost / watermarks)